# Summarising data patterns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have been given a large worksheet of data with a request to summarise patient blood test data. This is for an infection where a patient may be cured and reinfected, and my colleague wants a "smart summary" for each patient.

For example, say I have a spreadsheet like this:

```
Pat ID      Date      Result
123         1-Feb     Positive
123         1-Mar     Negative
```

We would like a summary, perhaps in a second worksheet, that simply states

```
Pat ID      Summary
123         Cured
```

The criteria for "cured" being "was once positive, but most recent result negative."

Other summary items would be "cured but reinfected"; "current infection"; "always negative" - hopefully all self-explanatory. I suppose the key thing is the most recent result and how the pattern of previous results relates to this.

I have tried playing with pivot tables and complex nested if statements but cannot seem to cover everything without arriving in a big mess.

My questions are:
a) Do you think this can this be done without resorting to VBA?
b) Any tips on how to approach this - I am literally scratching my head and not sure where to start

Comment: To summarize data Grouping can be used with combination of If then Else function. Better you upload some Proper Sample Data will help us to solve the issue. It can be done even without VBA also.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done.  I put your data plus some other test samples into a table named Tests.
[image: Tests table]

I then created a Results table with a series of formulas to derive (current) Status for each Pat ID:
[image: Results Summary]

Having used tables I could use structured referencing to make the following formulas easier to read.

```
F2: =COUNTIFS(Tests[Pat ID],[@[Pat ID]],Tests[Result],"Positive")

G2:  =COUNTIFS(Tests[Pat ID],[@[Pat ID]],Tests[Result],"Negative")

H2:  =SUM(Summary[@[Pos Count]:[Neg Count]])

I2:  =MAXIFS(Tests[Date],Tests[Pat ID],[@[Pat ID]])

J2:  =AND(SUMPRODUCT(--(Tests[Pat ID]=[@[Pat ID]]),--(Tests[Date]=[@[Last date]]),--(Tests[Result]="Negative"))>0,[@[Pos Count]]>0)

K2:  =AND(SUMPRODUCT(--(Tests[Pat ID]=[@[Pat ID]]),--(Tests[Date]=[@[Last date]]),--(Tests[Result]="Positive")),[@[Pos Count]]>0,[@[Neg Count]]>0)

L2:   =[@[Pos Count]]=[@Tests]

M2:  =[@[Neg Count]]=[@Tests]

N2:  =IF([@Tests]>0,INDEX(Summary[[#Headers],[Cured]:[Always negative]],MATCH(TRUE,Summary[@[Cured]:[Always negative]],0)),"No data")
```

The `SUMPRODUCT` formulas do the heavy lifting and warrant a bit of further explanation.

`SUMPRODUCT` takes `arrays` and tests them against conditions to return an array of TRUEs and FALSEs. The `--` at the start of each condition test converts the TRUE / FALSE arrays into arrays of 1s and 0s which can be multiplied so that of both array elements are 1s the result is 1.  If either is 0 then `1 x 0 = 0.`

In J2 it is testing Pat IDs, Test Date `= MAX(Test Date)` for Pat ID, Result for Pat IDs `=MAX(Test Date)` is "Negative" AND Pat ID has at least 1 "Positive" result.  If there wasn't at least 1 "Positive", then you can't be "Cured".

N2 is wrapped in an IF formula because I accidentally got a false "Current Infection" for Pat `ID = 127`.